# how to get the id of droppable item using sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

How can I get the id of the item where a dragged item is to be dropped instead, using  sortable. I can get the ID of the dragged item but can't get the ID of the item to be dropped instead. Here is my code for what have I tried so far:

```
$(function () {
$('#sortable').sortable({
    //to prevent items from moving around when draging
    containment: "parent",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        // get the initial position(index) of item
        var start_pos = ui.item.attr('id');
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);

   },

    update: function (event, ui) {
        var index = ui.item.index();//position of dropped
        var start_pos = ui.item.attr('id');//position of dragged
        alert(start_pos);
        alert(index);

        // Iterate over all <li> elements
        $.each($('#sortable li'), function (idx, item) {

           // $(item).html(html + ' - ' + (idx + 1));
        });
    },
    axis: 'y'
});
```

for example, if I'm dragging the item from position 1 to position 5 I want to alert 1 and 5

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code  :-)

```
$('.selector').droppable({ drop: Drop });

function Drop(event, ui) {
  var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
  var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Comment: I'm obliged to use sortable.I tried toArray to get all IDs .the aim is to resort the IDs once i changed the position of the items.but I don't know how to rearrange the IDs obtained from toArray